# What is the right way to install header files from some package?

Tags: c, autotools

I want to build some package from source (`e2fsprogs` to be more concrete) and install its header files to my system. After that I will delete the build tree so it will not be accessible anymore. What is the right way to do this?

When I want to install program, I make simply:

```
 $ ./configure
 $ make
 # make install
```

What are the equivalent actions when I want to install headers?

Comment: Have you _tried_ `make install`? Did you check if the header files was installed by that or not?

Comment: Of course I have. No, the headers were not installed.

Comment: I haven't built e2fsprogs in a long time, but normally header files should be installed in `/usr/local/include`. That's the standard for all autotools packages.

Comment: Joachim, I know this of course :) But trust me, there are no headers there after `./configure && make && make install`

Comment: Then you have to read the makefile to check for targets installing header files. There are no "standard" way of installing header files besides `make install`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For e2fsprogs**, quoting verbatim from the [`INSTALL` file shipped with the sources](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL;hb=HEAD):

> 7)  Install the include files and libraries
>
> You can run `make install-libs' to install the include files and
>   libraries.  Please note that this installation is not needed for the
>   programs to work.  It is only needed if you expect to develop other
>   programs using the libraries or if you want to compile other program
>   using these libraries (like the 4.4BSD dump and restore port).

**More generally though**, when I want to find out what is the 'proper' way to install something that has worked for others, I look at:

1. [What the package looks like, in my favourite distro](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/e2fsprogs/)
2. [How the package is built for my favourite distro](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/e2fsprogs)

Comment: Wow, even if it's reported in the `INSTALL` file, that still walks all over the principle of least surprise!

Comment: @ptomato - Sure does! Probably a 'feature' meant to make it easy to package the library and includes separately.

Comment: @ArjunShankar, not library and includes, rather executables and (library with includes)

Comment: @unkulunkulu - I meant 'library and includes' *separately* from executables. Same as you. But I guess I wasn't clear.

Comment: @unkulunkulu - Let's just blame my English, or even better: the grammatical ambiguity English allows :P