# How to add <mhash.h> into my C project

Tags: c, eclipse, hash, hashlib

I'm trying to run this code on Eclipse. But there is an error about the header **mhash.h**

### "Error: No such a file or directory"

**The code is this:**

```
#include <mhash.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    MHASH td;
    unsigned char buffer;
    unsigned char *hash;
    td = mhash_init(MHASH_MD5);
    if (td == MHASH_FAILED) exit(1);
    while (fread(&buffer, 1, 1, stdin) == 1) {
            mhash(td, &buffer, 1);
    }
    hash = mhash_end(td);
    printf("Hash:");
    for (i = 0; i < mhash_get_block_size(MHASH_MD5); i++) {
            printf("%.2x", hash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Where is mhash.h supposed to come from ?

Comment: I dont know how to add it to my includes.

Comment: What I'm asking is how you come to know about mhash.h. What is it ? Have you installed something that should provide you with an mhash.h header file ? The next thing you need to figure out if this is something you have installed, is where you have installed it, and where the mhash.h header file is located.

Comment: I'm asking it already. I havent installed  anything about mhash.h yet ? what should I do first ?

Comment: After installing the mhash.h file **PROPERLY**, it shouldn't be an issue including it. If it is an issue, it is because you didn't install it properly. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137033/what-is-the-right-way-to-install-header-files-from-some-package

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mhash first. Get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mhash

Comment: Ok, I got it. Then, How can I merge it to my project on Eclipse